# NSURLconnection fails on 3g 'network connection was lost'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an app that uses NSURLconnection that seems to consistently fail to communicate to a web service when using 3G with the error 'the network connection was lost.'  However, the app runs just fine with wifi.

Any ideas as to what could possibly be the problem?  Do I need to do anything special with NSURLconnection to handle 3G?

one NSURL code example I use.

```
        NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    if (conn) {
        XMLData = [NSMutableData data];     
    }
```

delegate methods

```
 -(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection 
 didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *) response {
    [XMLData setLength: 0];
 }

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection 
didReceiveData:(NSData *) receiveddata {
[XMLData appendData:receiveddata];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection 
   didFailWithError:(NSError *) error {
     self.errorLabel.text = [error localizedDescription];

 }

 -(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection {
     NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [XMLData length]);
     NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] 
                    initWithBytes: [XMLData mutableBytes] 
                    length:[XMLData length] 
                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   //i do some xml parsing on the data returned
   }
```

Comment: Can we see some code? Are you implementing NSURLConnection correctly? All the delegate methods? You don't need anything special to handle 3G connections

Comment: As far as I know the way I have implemented NSURLConnection is correct.  As I said, it DOES work, just apparently not on 3G.

Comment: @JesseDurham, Can u please state how you fixed the above problem, as i am getting the same issue in 3G network. In my case it always run to timeout, and gives error"The request timed out." Please help me fix it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start putting NSLog's in the delegate methods. Start with didReceiveData.

```
 -(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *) receiveddata          { 
            if (receiveddata != nil){ 
            [XMLData appendData:receiveddata];
             NSLog(@"didReceiveData :receiveddata is:%@", receiveddata);

            }
    else{ 
        NSLog(@"NO Data:%@");
        }

    }
```

Comment: I found the issue.  It was a dumb error on my part, not related at all to NSURLConnection.

Comment: well the delegate methods were perfect according to me,i would have started Logging more deeply to find the problem so as to resolve it, glad you fixed it!

Comment: @JesseDurham do you remember what the error was . I've got the same problem and just can't figure it out